# How to get array after convert by reduce()

Tags: reactjs

How to get an array after converted by reduce()?

Before convert:
[image]

After convert:

```
newProductsDetail = newProductsDetail.reduce((acc, curr) => {
      const { categoryName } = curr
      if (!acc[categoryName]) {
        acc[categoryName] = []
      }
      acc[categoryName].push(curr)
      return acc
    }, [])
```

[image]

I would like get `newProductsDetail[categoryName]`

Have any way to approach this?

Thanks to all of you!

Comment: Please provide expected ooutput and given input. The images are not of help as array objects are not visible.

Comment: if you need to access by category name you can have your data in object format ( only if order is not important ), else you can use find

Comment: you may be able to do so using a filter over the array

Comment: So you want to iterate trough newProductsDetail values?

Comment: And what do you want? Array or Object? cause you can call `newProductsDetail[categoryName]` from Object. And from images it seems you are getting array as output.

Answer (score 0):

Set initial value as object and not list as follows if you want to get hold of value from `newProductsDetail[categoryName]`:

```js
newProductsDetail = newProductsDetail.reduce((acc, curr) => {
      const { categoryName } = curr
      if (!acc[categoryName]) {
        acc[categoryName] = []
      }
      acc[categoryName].push(curr)
      return acc
    }, {}) // dictionary/object is initial and not list
```

If you only want array and some manipulation, try to use `map` to iterate and convert final output to `array` of something.

Answer (score 0):

you can filter it like this

```
productDetail.filter( detail => { if(detail !== undefined && detail[0] !== undefined) return detail[0].categoryName === myCategory; return false; } )
```